# My game app is running slow on my iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've been encountering some problems when testing my app from XCode to my iOS 6.1.6 iPod touch 32GB. For my game, images frequently fall and I am not sure if that is the problem. Someone told me that my app could be running slow because I have too much memory on my iPod, but I already cleared most of my memory.

My question is, how can I make my app run fast on my device?

It runs really smooth on my iOS Simulator but it's terrible after 5 seconds when tested on my device.

The code that makes my images fall is like this

```
imageView1.center = CGPointMake(imageView1.center.x+pos.x,imageView1.center.y+pos.y);

imageView2.center = CGPointMake(imageView2.center.x+pos.x,imageView2.center.y+pos.y);

imageView3.center = CGPointMake(imageView3.center.x+pos.x,imageView3.center.y+pos.y);


imageView4.center = CGPointMake(imageView4.center.x+pos.x,imageView4.center.y+pos.y);

pos = CGPointMake(0.0, 3.0);
```

I also have a timer set at 0.03.

Also, when every image falls, when it hits the bottom, a new image is made out of random. It's a loop.

Comment: "too much memory"? 32gig is STORAGE space, it's not "memory". an ipod touch has 512meg of RAM.

Comment: You need to run your app in Instruments using the Leaks and Allocations tools to discover if you have memory issues. Don't guess what is wrong - use the tools provided by Apple to FIND OUT what is wrong. Also, I simply don't understand this part of the question:`a new image is made out of random`. What does this mean? Please re-write your question to either include code that is leaking with output from Instruments or the relevant section of your code relating to images hitting the bottom of your screen. These should be two different questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Any UIKit operations frequently occur take a load on your iPods processor. Your mac CPU is so much faster and you've got a ton of more ram so that's why it works on the simulator.  You could try reducing the frame rate (the timer interval) and see if that solves the problem. I'd suggest you stay away from UIKit for making games and instead use the new iOS 7 framework, SpriteKit. (A google search will find the documentation) Frameworks like SpriteKit or Cocos2d are slightly more difficult to learn, but they have engines optimized for running games and using your iPods gpu. How complex is your game? If it's more than just one screen with moving objects I'd consider rewriting the entire thing in SpriteKit. Sorry to let you down on your first game but UIKit is nearly never the way to go when making games. Good luck!

Comment: Others can probably help you with the bug that's happening and like Marc B said, memory refers to random access memory, (ram, 512mb on iPod touches, I think) and not the file storage (32gb). Try running your app in instruments to see how much memory you app is using. If that number is too high make sure you're freeing objects when you're done with them (check out @autoreleasepool for example)

Comment: I guess my question was too hard. I working on the problem now, thanks for trying everyone.